# How to create an invitation system in Laravel PHP

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Im new in laravel and I'm watching a youtube playlist to build my 1st project....
now I'm trying to implement an inv only system
so the register form looks like

```
username:
inv code:
password:
```

I've already created a migration which has

```
user_id - this is user id of the user who created the invite
code - the code which will get validated at time of registration and then deleted
{timestamps}
```

so the issue im having is:
how do I verify that the invite entered by user exists in the table "inv_codes" and matches the column "code" and then delete it after registration is complete

here is a minimal reproducible example

```
lass RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['guest']);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('auth.register');
    }

    public function submit(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'username' => 'required|max:6',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        User::create([
            'username' => $request->username,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]);

        auth()->attempt($request->only('username', 'password'));
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code, especially an [mre]?

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](https://dev.to/simioluwatomi/let-s-build-a-super-simple-referral-system-with-laravel-1o3h). Even has a [Github repo](https://github.com/simioluwatomi/simple-referral) with code.

Comment: sure, ill add it as an edit

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would create a table to hold the invitations and an accompanying Eloquent model. On register, you can check if the invitation code the user entered is valid by using a couple of ways.

**Manually**

```php
Invitation::where('code', request()->inv_code)->firstOrFail();
```

**Validation**

```php
request()->validate([
    'inv_code' => ['exists:inv_codes,code'],
]);
```

In either case, you need to fetch the invitation and then delete it after registering the user.

```
$invitation->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have code column in both users and inv_codes tables. Now during registration, you can use validation. Something like this:

```
$request->validate([
        'code' => 'required|exists:inv_codes,code',
        // ... rest of registration fields
    ]);
```

Then you can delete that row in inv_codes table by something like this:
You can read more at: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-writing-the-validation-logic

```
DB::table('inv_codes')->where('code', $request->code)->delete();
```

You can read more at: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#delete-statements